# Postgresql: Concatenating regexp_split_to_table into a single string

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, I need to take an ASCII string like `CNR39XL` and turn it into a number like `21317392311` (ASCII values - 65, but digits left as is). This is to take some logic in our software and push it down into the databse level. I’m partway there with this:

```
ourdb=> SELECT CASE
ourdb->          WHEN ASCII(c) < 65 THEN c::integer
ourdb->          ELSE                    ASCII(c)-65
ourdb->        END
ourdb->   FROM regexp_split_to_table('CNR39XL','') s(c);
 case
------
    2
   13
   17
    3
    9
   23
   11
(7 rows)
```

However, I can't figure out how to take that final set of numbers and convert it into the string. What am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string_agg`

```
SELECT CAST(
          string_agg(
             CAST (CASE ... END AS text),
             ''
          )
       AS numeric)
FROM ...
```